# Fortran Derived Type:

Tags: object, fortran90, derived-types

I am confused by the following example:

```
TYPE :: car 
    real :: x,  u ! position, velocity
    real :: y,  v ! 
    real :: z,  w !  
    real,dimension(3) :: uvw_0    ! initial uvw
END TYPE

TYPE (car), pointer:: mercedes
TYPE (car), DIMENSION(m,n,q,r), TARGET :: mercedes_ay
```

It looks like an implementation of object, but what does

```
TYPE (car), DIMENSION(m,n,q,r), TARGET :: mercedes_ay
```

do with respect to TYPE(car) - what variables are referenced by DIMENSION(m,n,q,r)? What does mercedes_ay(1,1,1,1) mean? What does mercedes(1,1,1,1) mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays in Fortran?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All it's doing is declaring an array of `car`'s of dimension (m,n,q,r). Those dimensions aren't defined by your example code though.

`mercedes_ay(1,1,1,1)` is the first car in the array. So `mercedes_ay(1,1,1,1)%x` is the `x` position of the first car. `mercedes_ay(1,1,1,1)%uvw_0(1)` is the initial `u` of the first car. Etc..

`mercedes(1,1,1,1)` is impossible because it has no DIMENSION, it's a scalar. So it can only point to a scalar. Instead, it would likely be used like:

```
mercedes => mercedes_ay(1,1,1,1)
```

which would mean you are pointing `mercedes` at the first car in the array. It basically acts as an alias.